# Ajax form not submitting on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome

I have a form that is working on Firefox but doesn't work on Chrome. The form submits via AJAX.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row container">
        <?php if (count($products) != 0) { ?>
            <form action="/cmajax.php" method="GET" class="gform">
                <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_4'>
                    Alege Magazinul
                    <span class='gfield_required'>*</span>
                </label>
                <select name='cMagazin' id='input_1_4' onchange='gf_apply_rules(1,[0]);' class='medium gfield_select' tabindex='1'>
                    <option value='Bucuresti - Baneasa' selected='selected'>Bucuresti - Baneasa</option>
                    <option value='Craiova'>Craiova</option>
                    <option value='Constanta'>Constanta</option>
                    <option value='Cluj'>Cluj</option>
                    <option value='Timisoara'>Timisoara</option>
                    <option value='Iasi'>Iasi</option>
                    <option value='Pitesti'>Pitesti</option>
                    <option value='Sibiu'>Sibiu</option>
                    <option value='Targu Mures'>Targu Mures</option>
                </select>

                <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_1'>Nume</label>
                <input name='cName' id='input_1_1' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='2' />

                <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_5'>Telefon</label>
                <input name='cTelefon' id='input_1_5' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='3' />

                <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_3'>Email</label>
                <input name='cEmail' id='input_1_3' type='text' value='' class='small' tabindex='4' />

                <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_6'>Mesaj</label>
                <textarea name='cText' id='input_1_6' class='textarea medium' tabindex='5' rows='10' cols='50'></textarea>
                <input name='cID' id='input_1_11' type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' value='<?php echo $productsList; ?>' />
                <input name='cmd' id='input_1_10' type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' value='sendCerere' /><br/><br/>

                <input type='button' id='gform_submit_button_1' class='rovereButton button gform_button' value='Cere Cotatie' tabindex='6' />
            </form>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
    console.log('x');
    $('#gform_submit_button_1').click(function(event) {
        if ($('#input_1_5').val() == '') {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('Va rugam completati numarul dvs de telefon!');
            return false;
        }
        if ($('#input_1_3').val() == '') {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('Va rugam completati adresa dvs de email!');
            return false;
        }
        $('#gform_submit_button_1').prop("disabled", true);
    });

    $('.btnStergere').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var pidd = $(this).attr('data-cm-prodid');
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cmajax.php",
            data: {
                cmd: "remQuote",
                pid: pidd
            }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            location.reload();
        });
    });
});
```

I looked into similar topics, tried changing the type of the submit button to "button" instead of "submit", checked the document declaration and still haven't found a solution.

The console doesn't display any errors on chrome.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Is the request showing up in the network tab of your developer tools?

Comment: There is no `.btnStergere` element in your HTML. Also note that it's much better to hook to the `submit` event of the `form`, instead of a `click` on a button.

Comment: Can't find the request in the network tab, here is the link to the form: http://www.roveremobili.ro/cerere-cotatie (it needs to have a product added first so just click a random button on this page first: http://www.roveremobili.ro/mobilier/living/biblioteci/)

Answer (score 1):

Your $.ajax call is handled by $('.btnStergere').click, but then is no really a button with such class
You propabaly want to move

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cmajax.php",
        data: { cmd: "remQuote", pid: pidd }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
             location.reload();
        });     
    });
```

under

```
 $('#gform_submit_button_1').click(function(event) {
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/dba823wu/)

**try this one :**

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('#gform_submit_button_1').click(function(event) {
        if ($('#input_1_5').val() == '') {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('Va rugam completati numarul dvs de telefon!');
            return false;
        }
        if ($('#input_1_3').val() == '') {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('Va rugam completati adresa dvs de email!');
            return false;
        }
        $('#gform_submit_button_1').prop( "disabled", true );

    var pidd = $(this).attr('data-cm-prodid');      
    var btn = $(this);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cmajax.php",
        data: { cmd: "remQuote", pid: pidd }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
             location.reload();
        });     
    });     
      

});
```

```html
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row container">

        <form action="/cmajax.php" method="GET" class="gform">              
        <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_4'>Alege Magazinul<span class='gfield_required'>*</span></label>           
        <select name='cMagazin' id='input_1_4' onchange='gf_apply_rules(1,[0]);' class='medium gfield_select' tabindex='1' >
            <option value='Bucuresti - Baneasa' selected='selected'>Bucuresti - Baneasa</option>
            <option value='Craiova' >Craiova</option>
            <option value='Constanta' >Constanta</option>
            <option value='Cluj' >Cluj</option>
            <option value='Timisoara' >Timisoara</option>
            <option value='Iasi' >Iasi</option>
            <option value='Pitesti' >Pitesti</option>
            <option value='Sibiu' >Sibiu</option>
            <option value='Targu Mures' >Targu Mures</option>
            </select>

        <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_1'>Nume</label>
        <input name='cName' id='input_1_1' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='2' />

        <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_5'>Telefon</label>
        <input name='cTelefon' id='input_1_5' type='text' value='' class='medium'  tabindex='3' />

        <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_3'>Email</label>
        <input name='cEmail' id='input_1_3' type='text' value='' class='small'  tabindex='4' />

        <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_6'>Mesaj</label>
        <textarea name='cText' id='input_1_6' class='textarea medium' tabindex='5' rows='10' cols='50'></textarea>
        <input name='cID' id='input_1_11' type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' value='' />
        <input name='cmd' id='input_1_10' type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' value='sendCerere' />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type='button' id='gform_submit_button_1' class='rovereButton button gform_button' value='Cere Cotatie' tabindex='6' />
    
        </div></div>
```

Comment: If there is no button how does it work with Firefox?

Comment: No idea, I'm puzzled as well, I just have to debug the code, I didn't write it and frankly it all looks like spaghetti to me that SOMEHOW works on Firefox.

Comment: @KilianStinson it is dosent.  SporeDev is missing something

Comment: @SporeDev it looks quite simple I can help you with it